# Column level lineage in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to map source column to target column between two dataframes. I need an output text file containing source to target mapping. I'm new to spark and need this info. Can you please tell me how to get this?

```
Df = spark.read.parquet(‘/temp/file.parquet’)
>>> df.show()
+-----------+------+
|col1       | col2 |
+-----------+------+
|       1000|   185|
|        807|   185|
+-----------+------+

>>> df1 = df.withColumn('col3', df.col1)
>>> df1.show()
+-----------+------+------+
|col1       | col2 | col3 |
+-----------+------+------+
|       1000|   185|   185|
|        807|   185|   185|
+-----------+------+------+

Expected output:
Target    Source
col1  --> col1
col2  --> col2
col3  --> col2
```

Comment: shouldn't be df.col2 instead of df.col1?

Comment: yes that was a typo it should be col2 there